# $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{2n-1} f(k/n) = \int_{0}^{2} f(x)dx$

Tags: integration, summation

$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{2n-1} f(k/n) = \int_{0}^{2} f(x)dx$. Recently, I came across this equality connecting sum and integrals. Is this true? If it is, then Is there a general equality?

Comment: Sure (for reasonable $f$, e.g. continuous). It is just a left hand Riemann sum for $\int_0^2 f(x) dx$ with $\Delta x = 1/n$.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Connection_with_integration

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is true. From the definition of Riemann integral,  if $f$ is Riemann integrable over $[a,b]$, then
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f \left(a + \left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)k \right) = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$$

The LHS of the above thing says that we divided up the interval $[a,b]$ into $n$ equal intervals and took the sum of things of the form $f(a+ (\frac{b-a}{n})k) \frac{b-a}{n}$ and then let the number of intervals go to infinity.

Now, let’s say $a=0$ and $b=2$ and we divide the the interval $[0,2]$ into $2n$ intervals, then we have
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{2-0}{2n} \sum_{k=1}^{2n} f \left( 0+ \frac{2-0}{2n} k\right) = \int_{0}^{2} f(x) dx \\
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{2n} f \left( \frac{k}{n} \right) =\int_{0}^{2} f(x) dx$$

You must observe that when the function is integrable $k$ can go from $0$ to $n-1$ or it can go from $1$ to $n$, both expressions become equivalents.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That is not the actual definition of integral. It just so happens that if $f$ is continuous (and thus uniformly continuous) over $[a,b]$, the limit of the "uniformly space"  Riemann  sum tends to its purported limit, i.e. the Riemann integral.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Yeah, the actaul definition involves upper and lower sums. I removed the word “actual”.